# Custom error message for workflow rule

Tags: custom-object, workflow

I want to display a custom error message if my workflow rule fires and fails. Basically, I am trying to avoid duplicate dates. I have got my workflow running, but right now it displays the following message:

"duplicate value found: Unique_Key__c duplicates value on record with id: a04j0000002bTQs"

Is it possible to display a different message such as:

"This date already exists in a record."

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do following

1) Write controller and override the Save method
2) In save method use try cache block and show whatever message your want to show

```
try{
    update myObj;
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    if(exc.getMessage().contains('FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'))
    {
        Trigger.new[0].addError('Please select only active entities.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a code example @Atul?